# I have bought a mixed lego bundle and there is one set I cannot identify. The seller has sent this picture, any ideas what the second build is?

Tags: set-identification

This is a clone wars item I believe (so does the seller) but neither of us have a clue as to what, and its now in bits. Doulbe cannon at front (pivot sideways) 2 engines, not an AT. Side fins beside blasters are marked as 501st.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Searching Bricklink for pieces that have "501" on them results in [a delightfully short list](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=501#T=P), of which two possible items emerge:

- [75002 AT-RT](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75002-1#T=I)

[image]

- and [75280 501st Legion Clone Troopers](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75280-1#T=I)

[image]

The second one can clearly be seen in the first and third assemblies, and the palette of the pieces in the second assembly is strikingly similar to this one, so I'm quite sure it's a MOC of that one.

Comment: After looking at it for he last week, and having got the original 75280 set with this collection, I've come to the same conclusion, although now I start to build it, theres a lot missing from both builds.

Comment: @PaulThomas I'm glad the answer could help you in the end. If you're satisfied and don't expect more replies, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark so that others can see from the main page that this question has been adequately answered.